# How do I separate truffle environments when working on separate projects?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I have two truffle projects on my local machine.  When running `truffle test` on one project, the output indicates that all contracts from both projects are being compiled.  I'd like to only compile the contracts contained in the current project directory.

Things I have done already:

- Place each project in a virtual environment
- Delete the current ganache workspace and start a fresh one
- Run  `truffle migrate --reset`

The issue appears to be coming from the lines below as all contracts on the machine get listed after this output.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✔ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, truffle compiles all the contracts inside `contracts` folder within the current directory (the directory your terminal is showing).
running the `truffle compile` command in your truffle project directory will only compile the contracts in the current `contracts` folder, depending on the compiler version in `truffle-config.js` in the same directory.

> 

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.4.24",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
       docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
       settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: false,
          runs: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "byzantium"
       }
    }
  }
```

and when you want to use the `truffle migrate` command, you can give it a specific blockchain to connect to, like `truffle migrate --network myNetwork`:

> 

```
networks: {
    myNetwork: { // default with truffle unbox is 7545, but we can use develop to test changes, ex. truffle migrate --network develop
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  }
```

so you can configure each `truffle-config.js` file for different projects with different compilers and blockchains.
like this, you can have different virtual blockchains like `ganache` and `truffle develop` etc, and configure the `truffle-config.js` of each of your projects to connect the one of them. this way you can have completely separate projects running at the same time, let alone the different truffle compilers